# IOS - UIScrollView not scrolling with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have this structure

```
-Self.View
--CenterView (UIView)
---ScrollView (UIScrollView)
----View (UIView)
-----Contains other views
```

I am also using AutoLayout in this full structure, but my problem is that scrolling does no work even if i use this line of code after my Views are built:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [scrollAd setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];
}
```

This is the code i am using to build the Whole Structure starting from ScrollView:

```
-(UIView*)getAddAdView{

        scrollAd = [UIScrollView new];
        scrollAd.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:213.0/255 green:210.0/255 blue:210.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        scrollAd.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        scrollAd.scrollEnabled=YES;
        scrollAd.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        scrollAd.delegate = self;
        [viewCenter addSubview:scrollAd];

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary12 = @{@"scrollAd":scrollAd};

        NSArray *constraint_H12 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-10-[scrollAd]-10-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary12];
        NSArray *constraint_V12 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-10-[scrollAd]-10-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary12];
        [viewCenter addConstraints:constraint_H12];
        [viewCenter addConstraints:constraint_V12];

        NSArray *constraint_POS_V12 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[scrollAd]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary12];
        NSArray *constraint_POS_H12 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[scrollAd]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary12];
        [viewCenter addConstraints:constraint_POS_H12];
        [viewCenter addConstraints:constraint_POS_V12];




        viewAddAd = [UIView new];
        viewAddAd.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:213.0/255 green:210.0/255 blue:210.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        viewAddAd.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [scrollAd addSubview:viewAddAd];

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"viewAddAd":viewAddAd, @"scrollAd":scrollAd};

        NSArray *constraint_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[viewAddAd(==scrollAd)]|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
        NSArray *constraint_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|[viewAddAd(==scrollAd)]|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
        [scrollAd addConstraints:constraint_H];
        [scrollAd addConstraints:constraint_V];

        //NSArray *constraint_POS_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[viewAddAd]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
        //NSArray *constraint_POS_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[viewAddAd]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
        //[scrollAd addConstraints:constraint_POS_H];
        //[scrollAd addConstraints:constraint_POS_V];

        UIView *viewSelectCategory = [UIView new];
        viewSelectCategory.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        viewSelectCategory.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [viewAddAd addSubview:viewSelectCategory];

        UIView *viewExpiryDate = [UIView new];
        viewExpiryDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        viewExpiryDate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [viewAddAd addSubview:viewExpiryDate];

        UIView *viewKeywords = [UIView new];
        viewKeywords.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        viewKeywords.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [viewAddAd addSubview:viewKeywords];



        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary2 = @{@"viewSelectCategory":viewSelectCategory, @"viewExpiryDate":viewExpiryDate, @"viewKeywords":viewKeywords};

        NSArray *constraint_H2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-10-[viewSelectCategory(40)]-10-[viewExpiryDate(40)]-10-[viewKeywords(100)]"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary2];
        NSArray *constraint_V2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-10-[viewSelectCategory]-10-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary2];
        [viewAddAd addConstraints:constraint_H2];
        [viewAddAd addConstraints:constraint_V2];

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary3 = @{@"viewExpiryDate":viewExpiryDate};

        NSArray *constraint_V3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-10-[viewExpiryDate]-10-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary3];
        [viewAddAd addConstraints:constraint_V3];

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary9 = @{@"viewKeywords":viewKeywords};

        NSArray *constraint_V9 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-10-[viewKeywords]-10-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary9];
        [viewAddAd addConstraints:constraint_V9];






        textFieldSelectCategory = [UITextField new];
        textFieldSelectCategory.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:213.0/255 green:210.0/255 blue:210.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        textFieldSelectCategory.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        textFieldSelectCategory.placeholder = @"Select Category";
        textFieldSelectCategory.delegate = self;
        [viewSelectCategory addSubview:textFieldSelectCategory];

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary6 = @{@"textFieldSelectCategory":textFieldSelectCategory};

        NSArray *constraint_H6 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-0-[textFieldSelectCategory]-0-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary6];
        NSArray *constraint_V6 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[textFieldSelectCategory]-0-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary6];
        [viewSelectCategory addConstraints:constraint_H6];
        [viewSelectCategory addConstraints:constraint_V6];

        UIView *viewBorder3 = [UIView new];
        viewBorder3.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:201.0/255 green:198.0/255 blue:1- 98.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        viewBorder3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [viewSelectCategory addSubview:viewBorder3];

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary7 = @{@"viewBorder3":viewBorder3};

        NSArray *constraint_H7 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[viewBorder3(1)]-1-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary7];
        NSArray *constraint_V7 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[viewBorder3]-0-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary7];
        [viewSelectCategory addConstraints:constraint_H7];
        [viewSelectCategory addConstraints:constraint_V7];








        textFieldExpiryDate = [UITextField new];
        textFieldExpiryDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:213.0/255 green:210.0/255 blue:210.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        textFieldExpiryDate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        textFieldExpiryDate.placeholder = @"Enter Expiry Date";
        textFieldExpiryDate.delegate = self;
        [viewExpiryDate addSubview:textFieldExpiryDate];

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary4 = @{@"textFieldExpiryDate":textFieldExpiryDate};

        NSArray *constraint_H4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-0-[textFieldExpiryDate]-0-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary4];
        NSArray *constraint_V4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[textFieldExpiryDate]-0-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary4];
        [viewExpiryDate addConstraints:constraint_H4];
        [viewExpiryDate addConstraints:constraint_V4];

        UIView *viewBorder2 = [UIView new];
        viewBorder2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:201.0/255 green:198.0/255 blue:1- 98.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        viewBorder2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [viewExpiryDate addSubview:viewBorder2];

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary5 = @{@"viewBorder2":viewBorder2};

        NSArray *constraint_H5 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[viewBorder2(1)]-1-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary5];
        NSArray *constraint_V5 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[viewBorder2]-0-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary5];
        [viewExpiryDate addConstraints:constraint_H5];
        [viewExpiryDate addConstraints:constraint_V5];






        textViewKeywords = [UITextView new];
        textViewKeywords.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:213.0/255 green:210.0/255 blue:210.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        textViewKeywords.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        //textViewKeywords.placeholder = @"Enter Expiry Date";
        textViewKeywords.delegate = self;
        [viewKeywords addSubview:textViewKeywords];

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary10 = @{@"textViewKeywords":textViewKeywords};

        NSArray *constraint_H10 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-0-[textViewKeywords]-0-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary10];
        NSArray *constraint_V10 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[textViewKeywords]-0-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary10];
        [viewKeywords addConstraints:constraint_H10];
        [viewKeywords addConstraints:constraint_V10];

        UIView *viewBorder4 = [UIView new];
        viewBorder4.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:201.0/255 green:198.0/255 blue:1- 98.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        viewBorder4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [viewKeywords addSubview:viewBorder4];

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary11 = @{@"viewBorder4":viewBorder4};

        NSArray *constraint_H11 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[viewBorder4(1)]-1-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary11];
        NSArray *constraint_V11 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[viewBorder4]-0-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary11];
        [viewKeywords addConstraints:constraint_H11];
        [viewKeywords addConstraints:constraint_V11];


        //NSArray *constraint_POS_V2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[viewAddAd]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
        //NSArray *constraint_POS_H2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[viewAddAd]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
        //[viewAddAd addConstraints:constraint_POS_H2];
        //[viewAddAd addConstraints:constraint_POS_V2];

       //scrollAd.contentSize = viewAddAd.frame.size;

        return viewAddAd;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your issue. Please try UIScrollView's inset by set its bottom inset longer than view.size.height like this:

```
  UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bonds];
  [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.bonds.size.width, scrollView.bounds.size.height * 3)];
  [self.view addSubView:scrollView];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    //[scrollAd setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];

    UIEdgeInsets currentInsets = self.scrollAd.contentInset;
    self.scrollAd.contentInset = (UIEdgeInsets){
        .top = self.topLayoutGuide.length,
        .bottom = currentInsets.bottom,
        .left = currentInsets.left,
        .right = currentInsets.right
    };
}
```

This did the trick